# Is there a free tool that lets you go to definition on a method, and be taken to the implementation rather than the interface?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm new to TDD and MVC 3, and to make it all testable, everything has interfaces and dependency injection inserts the implementations. I have found this makes it quite hard to navigate around - is there a tool that will help fix this problem?

Eg. I have ICustomerManager and CustomerManager, but due to dependency injection everything stores references to ICustomerManager. I go to definition on methods and it takes me to ICustomerManager.

Comment: If you ever find such a tool then you probably shouldn't trust it.

Comment: There are lots of open source and free VS tools out there, I have a few installed - just haven't found one that does this yet.

Answer (score 0):

[ReSharper 6.0 Nightly builds](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds) - free

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> - "Navigate to" allows navigate to declaration (definition), implementation, and many other...

[image]

Comment: June 2011? I can't see any licensing, this will be for my work PC

Comment: @SLC: What kind of license are you looking for?